# How to subset the data frame according the value in a column

Tags: r

I have such a data frame:

```
value     date
2         09-12
5         09-12
3         09-12
0         09-16
1         09-16
0         09-16
...
```

There are totally `22` different value in the column `date`. I would like to subset the data frame in `22` sets, do yo know how to do it? Thanks!

Clarify:

my question is marked as duplicate now. Indeed, they are different. Subset or split one date frame is easy. But how can I apply them in a list of data frames? What I want is a list of subsets, not only single one.

Comment: `by()` or the combination `split()`/`lapply()`

Comment: With your new edit it would seem that by sets you mean a list with 22 elements, however this is not seen from your text or reproducible example. Hence the confusion.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks for reply. So how can I remove the duplicate tag?

Comment: Let us worry about closing/opening. Let's first see what you want. Can you confirm that you have a list of data.frames and you would like to subset all of them according to some dates? Can you show a small reproducible example to clear any doubts?

Comment: @Roman, I think they have a data.frame and they want a list of 22 data.frames according to date value (I'm just basing myself on *"What I want is a list of subsets, not only single one"*, the rest is rather confused imo)

Comment: can you check if `split(df, df$date)` gives you what you want ?

Comment: @Cath I have tried it and yes, that's what I want. Thanks!!!!!!